# Generating and deleting a dynamic textbox using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently the below piece of code gives me a textbox and an "add" button. While clicking on add button, a new textbox gets generated below the first textbox. clicking on "add" again adds another textbox and so on. But currently the new textbox does not have "add" button. i want an "add" button to each textbox as well. I also want a delete button for each textbox and clicking on it will delete that particular textbox in that row. Also, i want a validation that more than 10 textboxes will not be allowed on the click of "add" button.

```
Could aNY of you please help  !! Coding in both jquery and javascript would be appreciable.


HTML CODE :

<div id="inputs">
Name : <input type='text' name='name'>

<button onclick="getinput()">Add</button>
</div>


Javascript code :


function getinput()
{
var name="<br> <input type='text' name='name'>";

$("#inputs").append(name);
}
```

Comment: why don't you just try to modify the HTML being appended? Your question shows no effort on your part..

Comment: I think its better to have only one add button as **new textbox will always be added at the end every time** so it will be just a button repetition I guess.

Comment: As for the validation of not exceeding 10 textboxes.. how about `$(':text').length`? -- that's a hint, not a complete answer

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/yq670z0d/1/

```
<div id="inputs">
    <div class="input">
    Name : <input type='text' name='name'/>
    <button class="addbox">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>


$("#inputs").on('click','.addbox',function(){
    if($('.input').length < 10){
        $(this).parent().clone().appendTo('#inputs');
    }
});
```

Only jQuery, but quite short. the idea is to copy the div with your input and button, and then add it to your div inputs.

for your delete button, you just have to add a button with a delete class, and in another click listener, call the jQuery function remove() for the specified div. for instance :

```
<div id="inputs">
    <div class="input">
    Name : <input type='text' name='name'/>
    <button class="removebox">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>

$("#inputs").on('click','.deletebox',function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```